# pvcreate not found or ignored by filtering

Tags: linux, lvm, vmware-workstation

I am attempting to make my hard drive bigger for my vm which is kali linux.

The vm is running on vmware, I have increased the disk size and tried to follow these directions:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1006371

I got to step 8 and when I try to run pvcreate, I get:

```
~# pvcreate /dev/sda3
  Device /dev/sda3 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

The partition list looks like:

```
~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc9671107

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 121636863 121634816   58G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       121638910 125827071   4188162    2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       121636864 121638909      2046 1023K 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda5       121638912 125827071   4188160    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

So I am pretty sure it is there. I saw other postings about it being filtered by my lvm conf file, I checked it and the global_filter line is commented out.

I have searched and it seems all the ones I found solution are either not in the list or filtered out, I don't seem to have either of these problems.

thx!

Comment: Please post here the output of `pvcreate -vvv /dev/sda3` and `pvscan -vvv`. Moreover, use pastebin or similar to post your `/etc/lvm.conf` file.

Comment: It's there and < 1MiB (1023K). I'm quite sure that a PV needs even more than this just to reserve its metadata space. Thus it's filtered. Beside, you have sda5, meaning there's also a hidden sda4 (extended bios partition), both in the way to enlarge sda3.